# Syntax error: Missing operand after '10' operator

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code like this:

```cs
DataRow[] foundRows = dsFoxhillComp.Tables["RotaComp"].Select(findAssignee);
int test = foundRows.Length;
```

find Assignee is the result of this:

```cs
string combobox2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
string assignee = combobox2.Substring(0, 5).ToString();
string assignedShift = "";
string assignedDate = (item.SubItems[1].Text.ToString());

if (dateTimePicker2.Value >= Convert.ToDateTime("09:00:00") && dateTimePicker2.Value < Convert.ToDateTime("12:59:59"))
{
    assignedShift = "1";
}
else if (dateTimePicker2.Value >= Convert.ToDateTime("13:00:00") && dateTimePicker2.Value < Convert.ToDateTime("16:59:59"))
{
    assignedShift = "2";
}
else if (dateTimePicker2.Value >= Convert.ToDateTime("17:00:00") && dateTimePicker2.Value < Convert.ToDateTime("19:59:59"))
{
    assignedShift = "3";
}
string findAssignee = assignee + assignedShift + assignedDate;
```

This is, I hope, going to either find or not find something in my database, so I can then use that as a comparison for an If statement, I have seen people use similar things on different sites. But when I run it, I get the following error:

System.Data.ExpressionNode Parse()Syntax error: Missing operand after '10' operator.

I have no idea what could be causing this. Google searching had said something about apostrophes being in the dataset, but I've checked, and there shouldn't be. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably show `findAssignee`.

Comment: Good call, Ill make the edit

Comment: You still haven't shown the *value* of `findAssignee`, which is the important bit.

Comment: Thats the problem, I can't actual get as far. When I press the button to run the code, that error immediately appears and I dont get a debug option. It should be, if I'm correct, S100112022-05-17

Comment: @SDev95 That would explain, `S100112022-05-17` is not a valid selection expression. What exactly are you hoping to find/match with that string?

Comment: I have a concatenated field in my SQL database that creates the same thing, and I was hoping that I could use that string to find it, and then work off that for an if statement. I assumed, if I found it, the array would have a length of some form, so if it had a length of zero, I wanted it to write to the database

Comment: Right, but you need to specify what you're comparing against. Eg. `[SpecificColumnName] LIKE '%S100112022-05-17%'` instead of just `S100112022-05-17`

Comment: Oh cool, and sorry for bothering you, but can I compare against the variable? Just itll be different every time it's ran. Sorry about this hassle, university didnt explain how to do this and the coursework is due this week

Comment: So just call `.Select($"[ColumnName] LIKE '%{findAssignee}%'");` every time `findAssignee` is updated

Answer (score 0):

So, the comment from Matthias R. Jessen was correct and worked, so Matthias, thank you very much. So that there's a logged answer, what worked was:

```
 .Select($"[ColumnName] LIKE '%{findAssignee}%'");
```

As opposed to my original code, which I have now replaced.